# Uploading large files to Mariadb from cmd

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I'm using XAAMP and the information about database is as follows

[image]

I was trying to upload employees sample database from https://launchpad.net/test-db/ through CMD but I don't have much knowledge about mariaDB commands and all the information's on google is for mysql.

My command line for C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe opens as below not as normal mysql.

Notice the  `MariaDB[<none>]>`

[image]

I have set a custom password for the database in phpmyadmin for root.

What is the command line to upload the large mysql database from the folder 
C:\xampp\mysql\employees_db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that is very easy:

> **First**, you need to unzip the database in `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\` folder
>
> **Then**, you have all the `*.sql` files in that folder, right?
>
> **Now**, open a command line and type the following commands:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin\
mysql.exe -u root -p yourDatabasePassword < employees.sql
```

Comment: I have been working with MariaDB for years, on Linux and Windows environments, and that is how you can `create` the database based on the `sql` script, so try it first :)

Comment: Look at my answer...you just need to open a command line(Windows+R, and type cmd, hit Enter)..then nav to the folder with `cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin\` ... then paste `mysql.exe -u root -p yourDatabasePassword < employees.sql`

Comment: In that pic your are inside the MariaDB console...just type `exit;` and hit Enter

Comment: Also the `employees.sql` file need to be inside the `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\` folder

Comment: I have website restrictions in my work...but you can reach me out on my personal email `robert.rozas.n@gmail.com`

Comment: kkk..great..will mail you later